# VueJS - Apply CSS class only to clicked element

Tags: vue.js

I'm trying add a class to the correct answer. This code works, but when the key 'acertou' is true, CSS class 'certa' applies to all the li elements.

How can I add this class only to the li that was actually clicked?

```
<div class="alternativas">
      <ul>
        <li
          v-for="alternativa in perguntaAtual.alternativas"
          :key="alternativa"
          @click="corrige(alternativa, perguntaAtual)"
          :class="{ certa: acertou }"
        >
          {{ alternativa }}
        </li>
      </ul>
   </div>
```

Comment: Cause you're using same variable(`acertou `) for all elements. Try to use unique identifier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this way instead:

```
<div class="alternativas">
  <ul>
    <li
        v-for="(alternativa,index) in perguntaAtual.alternativas"
        :key="alternativa"
        @click="activeElement = index"
        :class="activeElement === index ? 'certa' : ''"
    >
        {{ alternativa }}
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>

export default {
  data() {
    return {
        activeElement: '',
    }
  },
}
```

On click, assign the index of the clicked element to a variable and apply the required class on the element where that variable and the index matches. You will require something unique for applying class or anything to a specific element. Here, index plays that role.

Comment: It is the same answer with mine

Comment: @omerS Nope, it's different. I am here using 'index' of the loop as unique identifier without implementing any methods. Why call a method when you can directly assign the unique identifier to a variable?

Comment: because there is a method in the example. So I thought putting it in that method would be better.

Comment: @omerS - yea sure but it's always better to provide a cleaner and efficient code while helping or guiding someone :)

Answer (score 1):

Maybe there is a better answer for this but I did exactly the same thing like this:

```html
<div class="alternativas">
      <ul>
        <li
          v-for="alternativa in perguntaAtual.alternativas"
          :key="alternativa"
          @click="corrige(alternativa, perguntaAtual)"
          :class="[activeElement === alternativa ? 'acertou' : '']"
        >
          {{ alternativa }}
        </li>
      </ul>
</div>

export default {
 data() {
   return {
    activeElement: null,
  }
},
 methods: {
   corrige (alternativa) {
     this.activeElement = alternativa
    }
  }

}
```

Basically with your method you say that my activeElement is this and it checks if activeElement is same with your item so it gives class to only that item.